# What is the next number of the following sequence 27, 54, 81, 135, 189,........

Tags: sequences-and-series

> What is the next number of the following sequence
>
> 27, 54, 81, 135, 189,........

Options Given:

1) 108
2) 243
3) 405
4) 216
5) 378
6) 486
7) 297
8) 459
9) 351
10)None of these

My Approach:

What i did is to follow this order of multiplication because the increasing difference does not satisfy the sequence.So i followed this

9*3,9*6,9*9,9*15,9*21..
Why i choose 3,6,9,15,21 as a pattern because they are all productive prime nos.So,3*1,3*2,3*3,3*5,3*7

So the next pattern will be 3*11=33

Hence,the next number is 9*33=297.

Is there Any approach you follow towards these kind of problems.

Comment: Increasing differences are $27,27,54,54$ , so maybe the next number will be $189+81=270$, since $27,54,81$ are the first three multiples of $27$.

Comment: This is a bad question. These sequences have more to do with pattern recognition than with mathematics. @Crostul's pattern is simple, and yours is quite simple too in the form $27\times (1,2,3,5,7 \dots )$ - but who is to tell which is valid? Many of us would not count $1$ as a prime number (it is a unit), which would cause us to query that explanation. No sequence has a unique extension, but here the ambiguities mean that even a criterion of simplicity cannot easily be applied..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could argue for $270$:

$$54=27 + 27\\
81 = 54+27\\
135 = 81 + 54\\
189 = 135 + 54\\
270 = 189 + 81$$

because then, the differences would increase by $27$ after each $2$ steps. The differences then go $27,27,54,54,81,81,108,108,\dots$

---

Or, you could argue for $297$ since the differences can also increase by a **factor** of $2$ every $2$ steps: $$27,27,2\cdot27,2\cdot27,4\cdot27, 4\cdot27, 8\cdot 27,\dots$$

---

But the question itself is stupid, because for all you know, the sequence could be $$27, 54, 81, 135, 189, 89236423, 32496234, 0,0,0,0\dots$$

Comment: In my view this is a proof that questions like this are not really dealing with mathematics. I 'choose' for $351$ purely on aesthetical motivation.

Comment: @drhab I agree. See the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: That made me decide to upvote :).

Comment: I think the answer is 108, because statistically the sequence just cannot go up all the time...

Comment: @5xum 1)How the question is stupid i didn't get you.2)There are two ans to this question.3) Is my approach also right.

Comment: @drhab How they are not dealing with mathematics.Can you give me some examples of it or any link which could be useful.

Comment: @Jack The fact that more answers are acceptable allready shows that we are not dealing with mathematics. So an example is allready at your disposal. A mathematical definition of "pattern" lacks.